# External jquery .click() event not working sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a simple jQuery time picker plugin that works on old bootstraps and jQuery, the jquery for the plugin goes in the sites.js and is called by putting  aclass on a div like so:

```html
<div class="time-picker"></div>
```

This successfully reaches the below jQuery but when i click the buttons they only sometimes run the functions which have been assigned to them

```js
$.each($(".time-picker"), function () {
    var div = $(this);
    var $timepickerlayout = $([
        '<div class="row-fluid">',
        '    <div class="input-group">',
        '        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-bottom:0; width:26px" id="hour">',
        '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" id="hour-up"></i></a>',
        '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="hour-down"></i></a>',
        '        &nbsp : &nbsp',
        '        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-bottom:0; width:26px" id="min">',
        '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" id="min-up"></i></a>',
        '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="min-down"></i></a>',
        '    </div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join("\n"));
    div.append($timepickerlayout);
    $('body').find(div).find("#hour-up").click(function () {
        console.log("click hup");
    });
    $('body').find(div).find("#hour-down").click(function () {
        console.log("click hdown");
    });
    $('body').find(div).find("#min-up").click(function () {
        console.log("click mup");
    });
    $('body').find(div).find("#min-down").click(function () {
        console.log("click mdown");
    });
});
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening will be greatly appreciated,
Many thanks in advanced,
Jaidon Rymer

Comment: __IDs in HTML must be unique.__

Comment: Use `class` names instead of `id`.

Comment: Also replace to `div.find(".min-down").click(...)` from `$('body').find(div).find("#min-down").click(...)`

Comment: That was an amateur mistake by me!!! thanks it works perfectly now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was solved by Satpal It was only the Id's that needed changing to classes as all other solutions changed the base functionality in some way, xyz's answer changed the base functionality and would be hard to use later on in my script because it needs to be self referencing and completely dynamic, and Dean Meehan's answer changes the layout so not what i want to do!

I shall be updating the progress of this time picker project on this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vonaje/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `id` attribute to `a` tag and make `id` attributes unique(one way is to use the index, as I did on the fiddle). [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mu9eyr45/)

```
$.each($(".time-picker"), function (index) {
var div = $(this);
var $timepickerlayout = $([
    '<div class="row-fluid">',
    '    <div class="input-group">',
    '        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-bottom:0; width:26px" id="hour">',
    '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"  id="hour-up-' + index +'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>',
    '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#" id="hour-down-' + index +'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>',
    '        &nbsp : &nbsp',
    '        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-bottom:0; width:26px" id="min">',
    '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#" id="min-up-' + index +'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>',
    '        <a class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#" id="min-down-' + index +'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>',
    '    </div>',
    '</div>'
  ].join("\n"));
  div.append($timepickerlayout);
  $('body').find(div).find("#hour-up-" + index).click(function () {
    console.log("click hup" + index);
  });
  $('body').find(div).find("#hour-down-" + index).click(function () {
    console.log("click hdown" + index);
  });
  $('body').find(div).find("#min-up-" + index).click(function () {
    console.log("click mup" + index);
  });
  $('body').find(div).find("#min-down-" + index).click(function () {
    console.log("click mdown" + index);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believe is that you have your event handlers attached to your italics HTML which isn't the actual button. (You should always attach it to the button itself i.e. the biggest thing that counts as the button.

Also you have got these items created on the fly, so using .click() isn't reccomended. You should use .on('click',fn)

I have made some changes to the code you have provided here: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/bw3L6273/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="time-picker"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.each($(".time-picker"), function () {
    $(this).html('<div class="row-fluid"> <div class="input-group"> <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-bottom:0; width:26px" class="hour"> <a class="btn btn-default hour-up" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">up</i></a> <a class="btn btn-default hour-down" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" class="">down</i></a> &nbsp; : &nbsp; <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-bottom:0; width:26px" class="min"> <a class="btn btn-default min-up" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">Min Up</i></a> <a class="btn btn-default min-down" style="margin-bottom:0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down">Min Down</i></a> </div> </div>');
});

//Moves these outside of creater code
$(".hour-up").on('click', function () {
    alert("click hup");
});

$(".hour-down").click(function () {
    alert("click hdown");
});

$(".min-up").click(function () {
    alert("click mup");
});

$(".min-down").click(function () {
    alert("click mdown");
});
```